# JavaScript innerHTML not setting the element style

Tags: javascript, css, innerhtml

Ran into a problem in JavaScript writing HTML code into innerHTML. Here is a very simple case I recreated. The problem is in the element style seems taking no effect, either using old font size or CSS style. The code has been tested on FireFox and Chrome in XAMPP localhost, and got same result. The text would be shown correctly but the style wouldn't. Any suggestion?

```js
tDoc = document.getElementById('target');
tDoc.innerHTML = "<p><font size='+5'>";
tDoc.innerHTML += document.getElementById("srcBox").value;
tDoc.innerHTML += "</font></p>";
tDoc.innerHTML += "<p style='font-size:20px;'>";
tDoc.innerHTML += document.getElementById("srcBox").value;
tDoc.innerHTML += "</p>";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <title>JavaScript innerHTML not setting the element style</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" name="ttBox" id="srcBox" value="My Title 2">
  <div id="target">NA</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: On a markup note: `<font>` hasn't existed for over 20 years now, it was removed from HTML4.1 in 1999. The only way you can set fonts through CSS (either `style` or, better, a `class`). Especially since you're using `<!doctype html>` which means you're telling browsers that your page uses HTML5.

Comment: Good point. <font> should not be used with <!doctype html>. I was scratch my head trying to test out things what could remotely be possible to give a warning or indication about the failure.

Comment: The answers that explain how innerHTML works pretty much have you covered on that front already.

Comment: Yeah, my problem is solved. Thanks for all who helped. Since I'm a newbie of the site, so I'm unable to up vote any answer. But I do appreciate the solution and the insight.

Comment: AH-uh. Glad to learn that. I just accepted the first answer, though the other answers are equally helpful in offering related insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't append to `innerHTML` in multiple steps like that. Each time you assign to `innerHTML` it parses the element completely to create the new DOM. If there are missing closing tags, it adds them. So when you do

```
tDoc.innerHTML = "<p><font size='+5'>";
```

it's actually as if you did

```
tDoc.innerHTML = "<p><font size='+5'></font></p>";
```

Then your next addition is outside the `<font>` tag, so it doesn't get the style.

Put everything into a single string and assign it to `innerHTML` all at once.

```js
tDoc = document.getElementById('target');
let html = "<p><font size='+5'>";
html += document.getElementById("srcBox").value;
html += "</font></p>";
html += "<p style='font-size:20px;'>";
html += document.getElementById("srcBox").value;
html += "</p>";
tDoc.innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <title>JavaScript innerHTML not setting the element style</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" name="ttBox" id="srcBox" value="My Title 2">
  <div id="target">NA</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the error in the way innerHTML was assigned. Put everything into a single string does solve my problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can't add partial tags to the DOM like that. The browser will not see the tags as belonging to a single element and possibly attempt to construct closing tags for the partial tag you append.

The simplest change is to add all of your HTML at once:

```js
tDoc = document.getElementById('target');
tDoc.innerHTML = "<p><font size='+5'>"
               + document.getElementById("srcBox").value
               + "</font></p>"
               + "<p style='font-size:20px;'>"
               + document.getElementById("srcBox").value
               + "</p>";
```

---

Additionally, you may want to escape the values obtained from the inputs. You can either manually escape them, or you can more effectively construct the individual DOM elements themselves rather than using a string.

```js
tDoc = document.getElementById('target');
const p = document.createElement('p');
const font = document.createElement('font');
font.setAttribute('size', '+5');
font.textContent = document.getElementById("srcBox").value;
p.appendChild(font);
const p2 = document.createElement('p');
p2.style.fontSize = '20px';
p2.textContent = document.getElementById("srcBox").value;
tDoc.innerHTML = '';
tDoc.appendChild(p);
tDoc.appendChild(p2);
```

The use of `textContent` to insert the text will prevent the injection of text as HTML code that could manipulate the DOM and cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: Get rid of the `;` at the end of each line.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up the security issue in user's input. May I ask, by assigning the input.value to a property as in p2.textContent, would that be good for providing an assurance to constrain the user input as "text"?

Comment: Perhaps I'd rephrase my comment regarding textContent. Would the practice of assigning user input to textContent prevent XSS attack?

Comment: @Papi314 Basically yes, the use of `textContent` in lieu of `innerHTML` generally prevents the injection of a HTML code, including scripts, into the page. If you are just taking input from the user and adding that directly to the DOM, I don't see much opening for any serious XSS attack, but the user can always mistakenly type HTML code or unknowingly copy it in from a malicious source. So I would still strongly recommend it over pasting user input as raw HTML into the page.

Answer (score 0):

Every time assign to the `.innerHTML` of an element, the browser will do its best to make sense of the input and will produce markup as a result. If the input is malformed and not valid syntax, the browser will make what it can from it and do its best to produce valid elements and markup as a result.

The generated markup/elements will *always* be well-formed; at no point in the JavaScript is the structure in the DOM invalid.

When this line is run:

```
tDoc.innerHTML = "<p><font size='+5'>";
```

The browser will see that there's no trailing `<font>` or `<p>` - but the resulting structure must be valid, so it ends those tags for you. After that line runs, the `#target` element contains:

```
<p><font size="+5"></font></p>
```

Then the next line runs:

```
tDoc.innerHTML += document.getElementById("srcBox").value;
```

But the browser has already ended the `<p>` and `<font>` tags - so that value doesn't get inserted inside those, but as a plain text node as a direct child of the `#target`.

The pattern continues for the rest of your code.

Assign the HTML string all at once, so that the DOM structure isn't created piecemeal.

```js
tDoc = document.getElementById('target');
tDoc.innerHTML = `
<p><font size='+5'>
  ${document.getElementById("srcBox").value}
</font></p>
<p style='font-size:20px;'>
  ${document.getElementById("srcBox").value}
</p>
`;
```

```html
<input type="text" name="ttBox" id="srcBox" value="My Title 2">
<div id="target">NA</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Assign the HTML string all at once does solve my problem. Appreciated.